# How can I reset Contact access permission, so OS X will ask again?

Tags: macos, security, osx-lion, abaddressbook, osx-mountain-lion

I know I can turn on and off permission in `System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Contacts`, but what I want to do is force OS X to ask for permission again. This is for testing purposes... I.e. I maybe have a bug that gets triggered when the permission request dialog is shown.

Any ideas where the "asked" flag is being stored, so I can blow it away? I've checked in `~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/` and a bunch of other obvious places.

Answer (score 23):

Just needed to do this myself...on the command line do:

`tccutil reset AddressBook`

**Edit:** This will reset for all apps that have requested access.

To reset only for a single app, just add the bundle id

`tccutil reset AddressBook com.id.bundle`

thanks Colin for your comment bellow.

Comment: This works great, however I'd just like to point out, that it will also clear all your other apps existing permission settings.

Comment: worth noting that you can add a bundle id to the end of this command to make it only clear one app

Answer (score 6):

Solution is
Go to General - Reset - Reset Location & Privacy.

Comment: Thanks! This also works as a way to reset photo permissions in iOS 6.

Comment: In fact that ONLY works to reset permissions in iOS. The question was about Mac OS